# Ошибка загрузки атласа в libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, текстурный-атлас

Запаковал файлы при помощи утилиты, на выходе получил .png и .pack файлы, оба 
закинул в assets\data. В коде пробую загрузить:

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas (Gdx.graphics.internal("data/temp.pack"));
```

Выдает:

> "Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data\temp.pack (Internal)"

Порылся по сайтам, заметил, что везде в примерах загружается файл с расширением .atlas, у меня таковой отсутствует. Как же все-таки правильно запаковывать и загружать атлас?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а другие ресурсы из папки assets загружаются? Вообще не важно как назван файл *.pack или *.atlas главное чтобы было точное имя, если на компе появляется такая ошибка, а на android устройстве нет - не правильно настроен проект, при запуске десктопного приложения нужно чтобы рабочая директория была assets, тогда ошибок не происходит